# Facets and Multiple/Stable/Deterministic Sorting in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Do facets support either:

1. Deterministic/stable sorting if there are equal values
2. If not, a way to allow this using multiple sorts. Sort first by A, then if A's are equal, sort by B.

This is my query:

```
POST /some_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "facet_name": {
      "terms_stats": {
        "key_field": "bucket_id",
        "value_field": "price",
        "order": "mean",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If bucket_id 90 , 91 .... 100, 101.. 105 all have the same mean price, then

1. Would I potentially get a different result set each time because of a non-deterministic sort?
2. If so, how do I change this specific query to order first by mean price and then SECOND by bucket_id.

Comment: which programming language you are using...

Comment: ruby , but is that relevant? the code above is elasticsearch dsl